# Print string between specific Tag from xml using batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have xml format like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<wsp1>
    <name>
        wsp1
    </name>
</wsp1>
<feature1>
    <name>
        feature1
    </name>
</feature1>
</data>
```

I want to print all the string between tag `<name></name>`.
I am using following command using batch file:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "xmlFile=testing.xml"
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%n in ('findstr /n /i /c:"<name>" "%xmlFile%"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "%xmlFile%" ^| more +%%n') do set "location=%%l" & goto endLoop
    )
:endLoop
    echo %location%
```

But this gives me only first `wsp1`.

I want all strings between all `<name>` tags only.

Comment: Batch script is probably the worst choice for parsing XML code. Switch to PowerShell (or anything else supporting XPath). However, try `echo "%%l"` instead of `set "location=%%l" & goto endLoop`.

Comment: I know about powershell is better, but my requirement is with batch file only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=2tokens=*" %a in ('find /v "<" q34149585.txt') do @echo %a
```

from the prompt should do as you request.

"find" finds all lines **not** containing `<` but precedes the output with 2 lines - one blank and one with the filename, so `skip=2` removes those lines.

You'd need to change the filename to suit your circumstances.

```
(for /f "skip=2tokens=*" %a in ('find /v "<" q34149585.txt') do @echo %a)>outfilename.txt
```

would put the result in a new file.

---

After responses: requirement is to produce a list of all entries under "name" tag, not "all string between tag"

It would help if you were to add data between the other tags and show the desired output.

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "printme="
SET "tagrequired=name"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (q34149585.txt) DO (
 IF /i "%%a"=="</%tagrequired%>" SET "printme="
 IF DEFINED printme ECHO %%a
 IF /i "%%a"=="<%tagrequired%>" SET "printme=Y"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q34149585.txt` containing your data for my testing.

`printme` is set to *nothing* at the start and on encountering `</name>`and to `Y` on encountering `<name>`

So - the sequence

```
<name>
    wsp1
</name>
```

will set `printme` to Y, then show the data value then set `printme` to *nothing*. `if defined` works on the current (run-time) value.

---

Adjustment fot tag1 or tag2

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "printme="
SET "tagrequired=name"
SET "tag2=whatever"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (q34149585.txt) DO (
 IF /i "%%a"=="</%tagrequired%>" SET "printme="
 IF /i "%%a"=="</%tag2%>" SET "printme="
 IF DEFINED printme ECHO %%a
 IF /i "%%a"=="<%tagrequired%>" SET "printme=Y"
 IF /i "%%a"=="<%tag2%>" SET "printme=Y"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: How this will find string between specific tag <name></name> only?

Comment: If I have another tag, assume <file>file1</file> inside the <feature1></feature1> tag, this will give wrong output

Comment: all though thank you for this code. It would be helpful to me

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it is exactly what i want

Comment: If I want to target more than one tags, does it work?

Comment: depends. Do you want to target (*tag1* **OR** *tag2*) or do you want *tag1* **within** *tag2*

Comment: @aschipfl: Not so. The space is optional. What I have posted (and what I post in general) is a direct cut-and-paste of actual working code.

Comment: It may function as is, but I'd insert the space though for the sake of legibility...

Answer (score 1):

It's generally more graceful to parse and manipulate XML as XML, rather than as text to scrape and hack. That way you aren't so dependent upon anticipating the formatting of the files you're manipulating -- line breaks in the middle of tags, for example. To that end, I suggest that you employ Windows Scripting Host and use the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object to manipulate the XML DOM.

The following batch + JScript hybrid example should be saved with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "test.xml"

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); }

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    xmlfile = WSH.Arguments(0),
    XPath = "//name/text()";

DOM.load(xmlfile);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes(XPath), i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    WSH.Echo(d[i].data.trim());
```

If you wish, you can add validation of the XML file for better error handling by inserting this below the `DOM.setProperty` line:

```js
if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + xmlfile + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}
```

If you want the text between two different tags, just change the XPath selector.  To search in tags named `tag1` and `tag2`, it would look like this:

```js
XPath = "//*[self::tag1 or self::tag2]/text()";
```

Answer (score 1):

download xidel, which can do xpath:

```
xidel file.xml -e "//name"
```

Comment: PowerShell can do xpath as well, and doesn't require any 3rd party downloads.  `powershell "([xml](gc file.xml)).SelectNodes('//name/text()') | %{ $_.data.trim() }"`  But OP commented above that his project requires batch only.